# Does an eslint rule exist to prevent a class from being reassigned?

Tags: eslint, eslintrc

We have some older code that follows the following pattern...

```js
class SomeClass extends Component { /* ... */ }
SomeClass = connect(
    mapStateToProps,
    mapDispatchToProps
)(SomeClass);

export default SomeClass;
```

What I would like...

```js
export class SomeClass extends Component { /* ... */ }
export default connect(
    mapStateToProps,
    mapDispatchToProps
)(SomeClass);
```

I've tried adding the rules that I thought would cause this to error out when linting, but it is either being ignored or I have the wrong rules setup.

So what rule needs to be added to prevent this from slipping by?

Comment: Show us the rules you added.

Comment: Linter was hung somehow... `no-class-assign` is the correct rule, which I had added, but it wasn't erroring out before.

Answer (score 0):

The linter was hung on something. After a reboot, the `no-class-assign` rule was what I was looking for! Posting the answer in case someone else has the same question.